# jQuery touch events

Tags: jquery, jquery-ui, jquery-mobile, touch-event

Как управлять `touch events`. Когда пишу несколько `touchstart` на разные элементы, срабатывают все сразу и не могу их разделить. Подскажите как правильно управлять ими без сторонних библиотек.

```
$(".content").on("touchstart", function(){
    $(this).stop().animate({top: '-50px'}, 600);
});
```

Если прописать в еще один `touchstart` на совсем другой элемент они сработают одновременно.

Пытался найти в гугле, но не нашел. Возможно не там искал.

Буду благодарен за подсказку или маленький туториал может где есть

Answer (score 1):

Не воспроизводится. Ищите, где у вас неверно проставлены селекторы или событие всплывает в другой элемент.

[Песочница](http://jsfiddle.net/LbISS/gxn6681g/2/)

```
$(".content").on("touchstart", function(){
    alert('content');
});

$(".content2").on("touchstart", function(){
    alert('content2');
});
```

Отрабатывает корректно, при нажатии на конкретном элементе выдает только один `alert`.